# Emacs Column based Narrowing or Folding

Tags: emacs

Is there column based narrowing in emacs.

I tend narrow in one everything between script tags but that still keeps the original indent (space before var).
It would be great if I could actually column narrow to the the beginning of the indent since otherwise the electrict indent tries to bring it to column 0.

```
<some html></some html>
<script>
    var foo = 1;
    var bar = 2;
</script>
<some html></some html>
```

Alternate solution could be to mark the starting indents as uneditable, but I am also not sure how to do this.

P.S.
I am aware of MMM and NXHTML and html-helper-modes, but I am not looking to use them due to complexities.

Answer (score 0):

Can you put { and } around the code within the script tags? It's not ideal but should keep the same semantics for the code and allow for the indenting (assuming you want one level of indent like in the example you gave).

Answer (score 0):

The [`table.el`](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/TableMode) package might be a solution. I haven't tested it, so can't be sure that it provides the solution you're looking for, but here's a quote from the mailing-list thread [rectangle operations - narrowing?](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2006-07/msg00551.html):

> there's a package, table.el, which does some stuff that's related, though coming from a different direction.  it's concerned with rectangular regions that are delineated by particular characters - but it provides for things like auto-fill and motion commands that are constrained to the bounds of those rectangles.
>
> (i mention this in the hopes that there's some unification of effort possible.  i am frustrated by the lack of control of the auto-fill in table.el, for instance, and would love to have it and related functionality generalized as you're suggesting, to generic emacs operations confined to rectangular regions.  it's too hard to get the current, specialized operations to do what i need.)

And here's a quote from [narrow-to-region for a rectangle](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gnu.emacs.help/i75hjElhvZM/gD5qLa0DQP4J):

> If one is interested in working with rectangles - edit text (with filling, justification, what not), narrow it (and have regexp matchers ^, $ do the expected) then one can look at table.el and extract portions of it to the Emacs "core".
>
> Remember, rectangle is but a table cell (possibly with no "geometric rectangle" surrounding it.)